# Overlapping clipping issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js, node-canvas

I have an issue where I am grabbing a users `displayAvatar()` and then I use an arc to make the image round. This works fine, however, I need to place a circle on top of that image, but it is getting cut in half because of the previous `clip()`

Without `clip()` : https://i.gyazo.com/b474c656f33a1f004f5e3becffcef527.png

With    `clip()` : https://i.gyazo.com/da13377cd3f6dc7516c2b8fd1f0f8ac9.png

I know that in the 'With clip()' image, it appears as if the arc border is showing outside of the clip, but that is hardcoded into the image, I put it as a guide with an image editor.

I tried moving around the code, I removed the line `ctx.clip()` and saw that my circle displays fine on top of the image.

```js
        // circle around avatar
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(122.5, 141.8, 81, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();
        const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(
            message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
        );
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(avatar, 41.5, 60.5, 162, 162);

        // presence circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(184.5, 193.5, 19, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.lineWidth = 8;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = userStatusColor;
        ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the canvas clip() definition:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp

> Tip: Once a region is clipped, all future drawing will be limited to the clipped region (no access to other regions on the canvas). You can however save the current canvas region using the save() method before using the clip() method, and restore it (with the restore() method) any time in the future.

Below is an example using the save and restore

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(90, 90, 81, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.save();
ctx.clip();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 50, 19, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = '#0000ff';
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(170, 99, 19, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually did try `ctx.save();` but I did not fully understand it, and never did `ctx.restore();`